# How to change fonts in motrola moto X XT-1060?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, moto-x

My phone is Moto X, verizon running 5.1 and I am unable to figure out how to change font for my phone as there exist no font settings under Settings > Display.

Previously I was using Samsung galaxy J5 and there were font settings under display but for my Moto, there is no such option even in applications from Playstore for this purpose. They won't just do not do the job as they redirect me to settings page and prompting me to navigate through Display > Fonts but as I already mentioned there exist no font settings.

Moreover I cannot root my phone as it just do not connect to PC due to some driver issues. So my question is that:

- Is there any way I can change font of my device without my PC getting involved?

Comment: The Moto X, like most retail Moto devices in the last 4-5 years, uses pure Android with only minimal enhancements from Motorola. Stock Android does not have provisions for changing fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Changing device fonts varies from device to device (it is normally found in Settings under Display section). From there you can change the actual font, as well as the font size e.g some Samsung Android devices let you change the font style in this manner. (Samsung has pre-installed a few extra fonts besides the default)

Not all manufacturers make this setting available to users. In this case, one has to root their device and add an application that can install new fonts in `/system/fonts` directory.

There are a few ways to do this if you're not able to root the device as in your case:

> One non-root way to change fonts on Android is through custom launcher
>   apps. Some custom launchers integrate the font-changing function,
>   while most others will need you to install themes.

One such launcher capable of doing this is [GO Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex) (Others include [Line Launcher](https://m.apkpure.com/line-launcher/com.campmobile.launcher) etc)

> To change font styles in GO Launcher, do the following:
>
> 1. Copy your `.ttf` font files to the phone.
> 2. Open GO Launcher.
> 3. Find the Tools app and open it.
> 4. Tap on the Preferences icon.
> 5. Scroll down to Personalization and select it.
> 6. Tap on Font .
> 7. Tap Select Font and tap on the font that you want to use.

Acknowledgements

- [How to change Android fonts](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-change-the-fonts-on-your-android-phone-32078/)